# Nginx Reverse Proxy: Proxying 2 different servers with using 1 server

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 1 Nginx proxy server but I have 2 different normal server. I want to proxying this normal server using just 1 nginx proxy server. It may be simple but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Here my code in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default (With this code I can proxy just 1 server):

```
server {
    listen       80;   
    #server_name 1ndwebsite.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

       location / {
          proxy_redirect      off;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass          https://122.122.122.123;
    }
}
```

I tried this for 2nd server but it didn't work.

```
server {
    listen       80;   
    #server_name 1ndwebsite.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

       location / {
          proxy_redirect      off;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass          https://122.122.122.123;
    }
}
server {
    listen       80;   
    #server_name 2ndwebsite.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

       location / {
          proxy_redirect      off;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass          https://211.211.211.213;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are you going to distinguish requests that should be served by server 1 from those that should be served by server 2? Why your `server_name` directives are commented out?

Comment: @IvanShatsky server_name directives not commented on real code. I think I can this with server_name but not working.

Comment: That's right, nginx choose the server block to serve the request comparing the `Host` HTTP header with the server name(s) specified with that directive. If none matched (or the `Host` header is missed at all), the first server block will be chosen (unless you specified `default_server` flag for the `listen` directive explicitly). If the second server block isn't working for you, most likely it is because of the `Host` header value and the specified server name not matched each other,

Comment: Thank you @IvanShatsky this is really help me. When I'm trying to enter `2ndwebsite.com` , `1ndwebsite.com` is opened. I understand now the first server block selected, but why? I'm change port for 2nd website to `:8080` but problem still here. Example if I'm enter the website on `:8080` port website open succesfully but if I'm trying with domain name this is not working. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know, everything should work as expected using the right server names. Can't it be some kind of cache? For debuging purposes you can temporary define some custom access log format and add the `$http_host` variable to it for logging to inspect its actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So interesting but I solve this issue with add `include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;` after the `location` tag.